# VBA refine code .PrintOut to define pdf Filename and current location

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have a macro that selects worksheets to be printed from worksheets that carry a value in cell A1.

I am trying to adjust the code so that it will print the pdf file with a predetermined name, eg "Output.pdf" and into the folder that the excel file is currently saved

I do not have the VBA skills to do it - I have been  trying to find code in various forums, without luck.

My code currently is:

```
Sub Print_All_Worksheets_With_Value_In_A1()
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Arr() As String
Dim N As Integer
N = 0
 Application.ActivePrinter = "Adobe PDF on Ne07:"

For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible And Sh.Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
        N = N + 1
        ReDim Preserve Arr(1 To N)
        Arr(N) = Sh.Name
    End If
Next

With ActiveWorkbook
      .Worksheets(Arr).PrintOut

End With
End Sub
```

Any help with refining this area i n particular will be greatly appreciated

```
With ActiveWorkbook
      .Worksheets(Arr).PrintOut
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a slightly different idea for how to do this.

You have created an array of worksheets with `Arr` variable. I think instead of this:

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    .Worksheets(Arr).PrintOut ...
End With
```

Do this:

```
Dim path as String

'Capture the path of the current workbook
path = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

'The copy method will create a NEW workbook with these sheets
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(arr).Copy

'The NEW workbook is now "Active", so use ActiveWorkbook and exportAsFixedFormat
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, path & "output.pdf"

'Closes the temporary workbook without warning
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Great - tested and worked a treat.How can I improve this by having the "output.pdf" file name linked to a cell on my worksheet, for instance linked to Sheet1!A2.

Comment: I have sorted the code to link to cell on my worksheet - pretty simple replaced "output.pdf" with & Range("Sheet!H2").Value

Comment: I was excited about this solution but the results are very unpredictable - many of the charts were blank and there were #ref errors everywhere.

Comment: If you've got ref errors most likely due to formula reference that can't resolve when you dump the sheets into a new workbook. This code pretty much assumes that the chart and data exist in the same sheets.